# How to check after sending an email

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I am using SES service of AWS for send email.

I use Python and boto3.
(https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_email)

I know how to check the overall statistics.
(https://aws.amazon.com/ko/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-email-opens-clicks/)

But I don't know how to do individual inquiry.
After sending an email, `message_id` and `request_id` are returned.
I think we're going to use `message_id`, `request_id` to search.
I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Configure SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor-sending-activity-using-notifications-sns.html) to send notifications (send, deliver, bounce, open) to SNS topics.
2. Write a Lambda function to listen to the SNS topics. When a notification is received, write the event to your table (I use DynamoDB)
3. Now you have all your email events in a table

Here is the Lambda function I use for writing SES events to DynamoDB

```
const tableName = "DEV_EmailAuditLogs";
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: "2012-10-08" });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

  console.log("From SNS:", event.Records[0].Sns.Message);
  console.log("Arn Topic:", event.Records[0].Sns.TopicArn);

  const json = event.Records[0].Sns.Message;
  const parsed = JSON.parse(json);

  const type = parsed.eventType;
  const sent = parsed.mail.timestamp.slice(0, -1);
  let to, subject, from;

  const headers = parsed.mail.headers;

  for (const h of headers) {
    switch (h.name) {
      case "To":
        to = h.value;
        break;
      case "From":
        from = h.value;
        break;
      case "Subject":
        subject = h.value;
        break;
    }
  }

  const eventData = parsed[type.toLowerCase()];
  let created;

  if (eventData && eventData.timestamp) {
    created = eventData.timestamp.slice(0, -1);
  } else {
    created = sent;
  }

  var params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Item: {
      to: { S: to },
      from: { S: from },
      created: { S: created },
      sent: { S: sent },
      type: { S: type },
      version: { N: "1" }
    }
  };
  
  if (subject){
    params.Item.subject = { S: subject };
  }

  dynamodb.putItem(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
};
```